# Use of: Noun + になります

Tags: grammar, keigo, sentence

As far as I know ~になります means "something becomes ~" but when combined with a Noun it seems strange to me.

A common example:
ご利用になりますか

Which is suppsoed to mean "Would you like to use it / make use of it" while the literal translation would be something like "does it become a usage".

My question is, why is ~になります used here and not some other potential form? Also, how does なる and する interchange? For example, what is the difference of 利用になる and 利用する?

Answer (score 7):

In this case, なります is not used in the usual sense of "to become", but as a marker of politeness. To be precise, it is 尊敬語{そんけいご}, respectful language. It is typically used by combining: お or ご, followed by a noun, and end it by になります.

A correct example that supposes evolution:

> 自動車免許を取得して、15年になります。

Typically, it would be replaced by です or だ in more colloquial language.

This usage seems to confuse even native Japanese speakers, as I found a number of articles (e.g. [1](https://nanapi.com/ja/107833), [2](https://careerpark.jp/54937)) that exhibit bad usages. ご利用になります seems quite common, given that it is present in all types of customer interactions:

> お砂糖とミルクはご利用になりますか？

As well as the potential form なれます to indicate the possibility, similarly to 出来｛でき｝ます

> Wi-Fiが無料でご利用になれます